# How to compare Floats with delta?

Tags: ruby

Is there in Ruby some functionality/syntax to compare two floats with delta? Something similar to *assert_in_delta(expected_float, actual_float, delta)* from *test/unit* but returning Boolean?

Comment: The accepted answer is fine, but I'm surprised there isn't a method in Float or BigDecimal to do this comparison.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
(expected_float - actual_float).abs <= delta
```

Comment: That's pretty much what assert_in_delta checks, aside from some extra assertions to make sure the arguments can be converted to floats and that delta is not negative.

Comment: Thanks! https://github.com/e-travel/evelpidon_core_ext/commit/7889913af630ec5c8d5465f7d137b2b48fc81c00

Comment: @NikosD: your test should probably test .006, not .005; you can't guarantee that (10.01-10.005).abs is <= .005 (for me, it is 0.004999999999999005 but the numeric imprecision is just as likely to make it slightly more than .005 as slightly less)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application and what your floating point values are actually representing, it might make sense to convert them to Rationals with a given precision. Then direct comparisons will always behave correctly since Rationals are just two integers.

For instance, if you know you're dealing with US currency amounts, storing them as `amount.to_r.round(2)` allows for exact comparisons for equality.

Just a thought... not all non-integer values need to be inexactly-represented floats

Answer (score -1):

you may also need a relative tolerance / delta calculation

http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=89